# Is it possible to write a C# wrapper for some C++ source code?

Tags: pi-3, c++, c#

I'm running Windows Iot (.NET Core) on my Raspberry Pi.  I want to use an RFM69 radio chip that runs over SPI with my Pi.

There's a great library I've used before on my Arduino RFM69 projects here: https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69 .  The problem is that this is code is C++.

In the past when I've needed C# libraries for SPI devices I just wrote them myself since it was pretty simple.  This existing library is very complete however, and I'd like to use it on my Pi without having to rewrite the whole thing.

Is there anyway I can write a .NET Core C# wrapper for this existing C++ code or am I stuck writing the C# library from scratch?  Any guidance as to what my options are would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You have a Stack Overflow account.  I have no idea why you would think this is the appropriate place to ask about this (I am positive goobering is right though; you can't make C# out of C++ source, particularly Arduino's oddball form of such, but you might be able to link and use a binary via some kind of adapter interface).

Comment: I have used Visual Studio to write a C++.Net dll. You can have a managed class in C++.Net call a non-managed class or function. You can also have C# link to a C style dll or shared library.

Answer (score 1):

My C++ is in no way good, but I'm very dubious that this is possible. The code looks (at least to my untrained eye) to be littered with references to Arduino-specific libraries referencing Arduino-specific hardware. I think you'll probably need to rewrite it.

If you want to take a crack at it, the way I've called unmanaged C++ code from C# code in the past is using [Platform Invoke (PInvoke)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) from the [System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices(v=vs.110).aspx). That's definitely included in the .Net Core API. It's not the easiest thing you'll do all morning and warrants explanation beyond the scope of the Pi board. There are currently [over 9000 hits](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+pinvoke) for C#/PInvoke on StackOverflow, so if you need a leg-up I'd start by combing through a couple of tutorials and past questions there.

Comment: If this means what I think it means (see my comment on the question) then you'd have to try and compile the Arduino code for arm as a shared lib (I think on Win you call them "dlls") -- normally the binary is for flashing to an Atmel MC.  I doubt very much that will work out.